# Google+ share link always pick the open graph image

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, share, facebook-opengraph

I'm using the share link Google+: https://plus.google.com/share?hl=fr&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2F

I wanted to know how to force Google+ to share the `<meta itemprop='image'>` instead of the `<meta property='og:image'>`. It always picks the Open Graph image which is used for Facebook share.

Here is my meta tags:

```
<meta content="website" property="og:type">
<meta content="Something great" property="og:title">
<meta content="http://mywebsite.com/" property="og:url">
<meta content="My description blaah." property="og:description">
<meta content="http://mywebsite.com/img/image-fot-.png" property="og:image">

<meta content="Something great" itemprop="name">
<meta content="My description blaah." itemprop="description">
<meta content="http://mywebsite.com/img/image-for-googleplus.png" itemprop="image">
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using valid schema.org markup. It should be included in the HTML that is visible to users and should include an itemscope. The [docs has a good example](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) and the best way to test if it's valid markup is using [Google's testing tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="{image-url}" />
  <p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: +1 for the Google's testing tool link, but I'm not sure about the itemprop in the <body> tag. In the docs, if you use the snippet generator, you can choose if you want it in <head> or <body>. On the other hand, I agree that I didn't set any itemscope. I'll try and see if I should put your answer as correct.

Comment: I see that. It's odd because I can't find any mention of meta tag support on the schema.org site. It'll be hard for us to help further without a link to your site.

Comment: This has not fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This Script Code for Schema Data:

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
        {
            "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
            "@type": "LocalBusiness",
            "name": "website",
            "url": "http://www.website.com/",
            "logo": "http://www.website.com/images/logo.png",
            "image": "http://www.website.com/images/dhaka-city.jpg",
            "title": "Title of your website | website.com",
            "description": "website.com is your online business directory of Country",
            "address": {
                "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "streetAddress": "Road #21, Gulshan, Dhaka, Bangladesh ",
                "addressLocality": "Gulshan",
                "addressRegion": "Dhaka",
                "postalCode": "1200",
                "addressCountry": "Bangladesh"
            },
            "telephone": "+880123456789",
            "geo": {
                "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
                "latitude": "23.783127",
                "longitude": "90.394359"
            },
            "openingHours": "Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr 09:00-18:00",
            "contactPoint": {
                "@type": "ContactPoint",
                "contactType": "Customer support & query",
                "telephone": "+880123456789"
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Open Graph data of Google and Other Sharing Media:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of your website | website.com"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="Most popular business directory of Bangladesh"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.website.com/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.moumaachi.com/images/dhaka-city.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="@website"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="Author"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="website.com is your online business directory of Country"/>
```